# Centered image with flanking gradients not working in all browsers

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="test">
    <img src="http://www.luzchem.com/images/up1.jpg"/>
</div>
```

With this CSS:

```
.test 
{
    position: relative;
    /* font-size: 30px; */
    /* z-index: 1; */
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
.test:before, .test:after 
{
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    content: '\a0';
    /* background-color: red; */
}
.test:before 
{
    margin-left: -50%;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, blue, white); /* For Safari */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, blue, white); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, blue, white); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, blue, white); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
.test:after
{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, white, blue); /* For Safari */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, white, blue); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, white, blue); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, white, blue); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
```

It does exactly what I want in Firefox and Chrome but behaves badly in Safari (left gradients is missing), Opera (blue bar to right of image) and IE (left gradients is missing and blue bar to right).  I have created the following JSFiddle to help:

http://jsfiddle.net/BigMac66/5rmAQ/4/

What must be done to get it to work in all browsers the way it does in Firefox and Chrome?

UPDATE:
The final solution does not have to use the psuedo-elements before and after.  I have considered using three DIVs...

Comment: A clue: I changed `margin-left:-50%` to `margin-left:-10%` and the left gradients started to show (although not in the correct position). Maybe -50% positions them offscreen?

Comment: That fixes the missing margin for Safari and IE but that fix then breaks Firefox and Chrome!

Comment: Yeah, not ideal. Maybe you can make a single gradient using this tool: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/5rmAQ/6/ (Wrong colors, I know.)

Comment: I tinkered with the left margin of the after element (set to -2%) and fixed the bar on Opera, but no matter what I do IE and Safari want the left margin to be very different from all the other browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what I saw I did not find any beautiful solution, maybe you can use conditional css, there at least will have the result that you expect

Comment: How do you get conditional CSS to work in IE - I am using IE 11 at the moment but need to support older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

How about something simpler. Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kU3B9/1/).

```
<div class="wrap"><img src="http://placehold.it/100" alt="fpo" /></div>

.wrap {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 0;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 0, from(blue), color-stop(0.5, transparent), to(blue));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, blue, transparent 50%, blue);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, blue, transparent 50%, blue);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, blue, transparent 50%, blue);
    background-image: linear-gradient(left, blue, transparent 50%, blue);
}
```

Comment: What this does is place the image over top the gradient which results in an abrupt change of white to blue at the edges of the image.  I want the edges of the image to fade to blue as you go away from the image.

Comment: And you can't use an alpha channel PNG?

Comment: If I knew how maybe... Is it something that can be explained quickly or can you point me to a good tutorial?

Comment: Here's a good tutorial on the basic procedure (basically, in Photoshop create an alpha channel then use linear gradient) http://www.photoshopcafe.com/tutorials/alphapaint/alphapaint.htm Note, the final step which is not shown would be to Save for Web as PNG-24